# Tips for brewing at high temperatures

Tags: fermentation, yeast, fermentation-temperature, cooling

I live in a tropical country and don't have an extra freezer, but I want to comeback to homebrewing. I'll dare to brew at high temperatures and would like to find ways to get a decent tasting beer. Here are some tips that I collected, can you give some more tips and recommendations?

### Recipes

Try to brew English bitters or Belgian ales. If you like (I don't) saison is best.

### Yeast Strains

Some strains support better high temps. Here is a list I collected:

- US-05
- White Labs WLP065 (American Whiskey Yeast) — 75-82 °F (24–28 °C)
- White Labs WLP665 (Flemish Ale Blend) — 68-80°F (20 –27 °C)
- Wyeast 1388 (Belgian Strong Ale) — 64-80° F (18-27° C)
- Wyast 3725 (PC Biere de Garde) — 70-84 °F (21-29 °C)
- Wyeast 3763 (Roeselare Ale Blend) — 65-85 °F (18-30 °C)
- Wyeast 3822 (PC Belgian Dark Ale) — 65-80 °F (18-27 °C)
- [WLP644](https://www.reddit.com/r/Homebrewing/comments/28ncze/recipes_that_tolerate_warm_fermentation/cicrgml/)

### Wet T-Shit Cooling

Cool it with a wet t-shirt over your fermenter, put it over an bowl with some ice, water and salt, and use a fan to accelerate the evaporation. It will get some degrees down.

During fermentation, the temp of the wort will be 5-8 degrees higher than the ambient temp.

### Process

Chill your wort till room temperature.

Leave a couple of weeks maturing after the 2-3 days of initial fermentation. Also more time in the bottle.

Here the main 2 pages where I gathered this info:

- [Beer and Wine Journal](http://beerandwinejournal.com/high-temp-yeast/)
- [Brew Magazine](https://byo.com/mead/item/1084-make-me-sweat-cool-tips-for-hot-weather-brewing)

Comment: Chlorine? Don't you mean salt? Ice salt water will be lower temperature than regular ice water. I don't think I'd want to get chlorine anywhere near my beer! (and as described would probably be dangerous)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't live in a tropical climate, but summers here get quite hot (chicago IL)

during the summer I use a Large rubbermade Tote, and fill it with water and put my fermentation buckets into it. 
it keeps my temperature stable around 70F, and if I need to get it to a lower temp, I add Ice, or frozen water bottles to it.

Comment: Good one! Evaporation may lower the temperature a few degrees indeed.
This may actually be an ideal choice for my situation: Holland, I have my stuff under the roof, it's isolated and the temperature are normally around 10-15°C (50-59°F) in the summer if may raise up to 20ish (68F) whit only a few days were it may reach 30 (86) or more. I could easily put the carboys into a bucket with water these few days.

Answer (score 9):

I advise looking at HotHead from Omega Labs: http://www.omegayeast.com/portfolio/14158-2/

- Flocculation: Medium-High
- Attenuation: 75-85%
- Temperature Range: 62-98° F (16-37° C)
- Alcohol Tolerance: 11% ABV

Comment: Great tip. Some opinions about: https://www.reddit.com/r/Homebrewing/comments/3vxala/my_experience_with_omega_hothead_ale_oyl057_yeast/

Answer (score 1):

Kveik yeast are also being recommended : [Which are the good yeasts and beer styles for fermenting at higher temperatures?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/25432/14909)

It can get as hot as 40º C