# Yeast suggestions for high temperature brewing

Tags: yeast, beer, temperature

Summer is here and it isn’t quite the end of the world, yet. So, I’d figure I might pick up brewing again.

**I’m looking for yeast suggestions for a low (neutral) phenolic profile at high temperatures.** But also stay clear of Saison all together this time around. I’ve read [this post](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/20218/tips-for-brewing-at-high-temperatures) and also found one potential candidate [Safale K-97](https://www.hembryggeriet.se/fermentis-safale-k-97-jaest) and discarded a one on passed attempts. Namely US-05.

In terms of style I’m looking for something that could work with ale style hops. I got Jester, Nelson, and quite a few classic style APA hops of many varieties. Additionally, I have plenty of porter hops which I don’t intend to use ATM.

Passed experiences have rendered the beer too phenolic. Only Belgian Stong Ales or Wit has made a decent drinkable beer at higher temperatures.

My temperatures are around 20-28 C (68 F to 81 F).

Comment: Have you looked at the Norwegian Kveik strains? Low phenolics and work at higher temperatures and clear very well. If you keep it more towards the lower end of your range, it should be very clean.

Comment: Of you post this as an answer I’ll probably award you the correct answer. A neutral flavor profile ale was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the high end (81F) plus an additional couple of degrees generated by the yeast there isn't much except Kveik that would make decent beer.

At the lower end, there are some Ale-strains that would produce okay beer, I suspect that you will have better results by finding a cooler room - or try to investigate some cooling hacks (wet wrapping + fan, or immersed in cooler water that you replace every now and then, i.e. in the tub).

[image: Borrowed from LugWrench]