# Which are the good yeasts and beer styles for fermenting at higher temperatures?

Tags: yeast, fermentation-temperature

I don't have space for a freezer, and I live in a tropical country. Which kind of yeast is appropriate for fermenting at higher temperatures? And which styles are best for these yeasts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally belgian tripels / weizen /saison  beers are happy to ferment at more temperatures. Higher temperatures lead to higher ester production which results in the 'belgian-ey' flavors of banana and clove (Although I really wouldn't describe it as clove personally) which makes them work better in higher temps. In my experience- you'll get sick of these styles after a few hundred bottles :)

However these days they're are some "kviek" yeasts which can ferment at high temperatures (90F+) and produce a fairly clean low-ester ale of any kind. So part of it may be which strains are available to you.

Comment: It's a cool , err, hot yeast! Never heard about it before: https://thetakeout.com/what-is-kveik-yeast-1835131715 and https://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/264.html are good articles. Now I must find a good recipe.

Comment: Another good article about how to use Kveit https://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/393.html

Comment: I have had a pretty good experience with Kviek yeasts. Though I've never ran it really really hot before, but I've read reports from many who have with great results. I think it would be your best choice if you want to create something that isn't ester-forward like belgian beer.

Answer (score 2):

Florida man here. You want Kveik. It will happily produce clean beers at temps above 100F (~40C). I've pitched it into 110 degree wort and it thrives. Minimum temperature for it is around the mid 70Fs(~24C). Below 85F(~30C) or so, kveik tends to produce clean fermentations, and behaves like a generic ale yeast imo. In the high 80Fs(~27C) to 100Fs(38C), it produces non-offensive fruit character. Extremely tolerant of high gravity brewing.

I've currently got a german style dark beer (fermenting at 75F(24C) and a mead brewing (ambient temperature, 85F(30C) daytime, 70F(21C) night) with Kveik yeast. I've previously had success with several other beer styles. This yeast is great for high gravity NEIPA styles, especially if fermented at higher temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with Mangrove Jack's M20 and M29 in high temperature. Last summer, I used them to brew a weizen and saison beer, at temperatures between 25° and 30° C. No off-flavors, although that might also be because the beers I brewed with them were not that big, OG of around 1.040.

You could brew other beers than weizen with the M20. Despite it being a weizen yeast, it has a relatively good flocculation. I brewed a Leffe clone with it. Don't use it for anything hoppy (except bitterness), hop taste and aroma definitely get muted.

The M29 is a var. diastaticus yeast. If you want more body, you will have to use more caramel/crystal malts. Mash at 62°, 66° or 69° C, it will all get eaten by this beast.
However, it is a very versatile yeast, which allows you to brew saison style, triple style and more or less hoppy styles. I brewed a single hop saison, with Merkur hops, which tasted terrific.

That is my experience with some high temperature resilient yeasts.

Answer (score 1):

I use Lallemand's Kveik dry yeast when it becomes warm in my brew cellar. Over the past year I have brewed IPA's, APA's, ESB's and English ales with Kveik, and all have turned out more than satisfactory. This yeast is rated to ferment up to 39degC, which I find quite incredible. It probably reaches a maximum of 29-30degC in my cellar. I use this yeast exclusively once my ambient temperature exceeds 20degC, with a maximum of 25degC being experienced in the past 12 months.
The yeast is rated as neutral, and this is also my experience. A god send, as I can now brew all year round, instead of the previous 6-8 month window.